# How to show only certain items in SEBLOD

Tags: joomla-3.x, seblod

I have created a site and used **SEBLOD** to create some custom content (a restaurant menu).

I am not sure where to find the content that gets saved, and searching PHP MyAdmin hasn't really helped me at all.

That is causing my next problem, where to find the content so I can call it again.

The content does appear in the front end, so it is getting saved somewhere.  What I really want to do is only call content based on the results of a certain field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer.

For my situation I **created a simple dropdown** named "type of food" in the dropdown the options were "starter", "main", etc.

I **added this dropdown** to **list/search > Search**.  Then I pressed **number 2** (live variable) and I **typed in the name** of one of the items (e.g. starter).  Then I pressed **number 1** and set the field to **hidden**.

I had to replicate this search for each course because you cannot duplicate the field without using a custom override, which I didn't have time to do.

After that, I **created a module** and called my search (starter list/search).  That way I could use modules for each course, and the modules were easy to position.

I ended up creating a custom HTML module called "menu layout" and using {loadposition starter}{loadposition main} in order to keep control of my layout without using up all of the slots in my template.

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Hello @Eoin and thanx for sharing the solution with us. At the moment I have no need for using it, but who knows what the future holds...